# What does f(•) mean?

Tags: calculus

I'm reading the calculus test's answers and the professor wrote that representing the function. I wonder what the dot inside means.

"Given a function $F(x) = \frac{x^2+ 1}{x^2-1} \ , F$(•)
 doesn't touch the x axis in any point"

Comment: Can you give more context for this?

Comment: I think it's best to ask your professor.

Comment: It usually is a means to indicate that $f$ is a function of one variable, but avoiding specifying  a variable name. But it could mean something else, depending on context.

Comment: I agree with Thomas Andrews. Without any more context, I would assume the dot is just a placeholder telling you "this is where you would put your variable, if you have one".

Comment: And, if this appears in the answers to a calculus test without having been used in class and in the textbook, it may indicate that the professor (or whoever wrote the answers) has forgotten what audience he/she is writing it for.  Of course it could be that it has been used in class and in the textbook and you just weren't paying attention.

Comment: The point should be understood as a "place holder". It is synonym of "f" without anything else. It is useful mainly when you work with for example two variables: writing $f$(•,5) means that the second variable is fixed at value $5$, whilst the first one is free.

Comment: @Robert Israel I think he used only for notation, maybe he just wanted us to search for it . I'm using James Stewart and Leithold, I still didn't see  f(•) on the books.

Comment: Thank You for all the comments! They are really helpfull!

Comment: If that is exactly what the professor wrote, it is bizarre: there is a sort of pedanticism in $f(•)$, but then a logical blunder in the phrase "given a function $\frac{x^2+1}{x^2-1}$," because an expression is not a function.

Comment: @symplectomorphic my mistake, I made a correction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ and $B$ are sets we may define "single variable" functions between $A$ and $B$ as subsets of $A\times B$. Clearly this function is itself a set, but the elementary notation $f(x)$ to denote a function is also used for the evaluation of $f$ at $x$ (an element of $B$) rather than the function itself (a subset of $A\times B$). Merely saying $f:A\rightarrow B$ however leaves the number of arguments $f$ takes into doubt. $f(\cdot)$ is a way specifying there is a single argument while not confusing $f$ with some value in its range.

Comment: I'd also like to add that this formal notation is probably overkill for a calc class, where confusion between a function and a point in its range is atypical.

Answer (score 1):

My complex analysis professor addressed this yesterday. He said

> Normal people write it like this "f(x)".

Where the text in quotes appeared on the chalkboard.

Comment: @JPelter bahahaha! A fellow I would surely enjoy.